# Create callBack with hilt - android kotlin

Tags: android, callback, dagger, dagger-hilt, kotlin-android

I write a callback with hilt and it good work when I test it just for call. But when I use like bellow get me `*throw catch*`:

My Interface is:

```
interface ButtonCallback {
    fun onButtonClick()
}
```

And Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
interface ButtonCallbackModule {
    @Binds
    fun bindButtonCallback(activity: MainActivity): ButtonCallback
}
```

And Handler:

```
class ButtonHandler @Inject constructor(private val callback: ButtonCallback) {
    fun setButtonClickListener(imageButton: ImageButton) {
        imageButton.setOnClickListener {
            // Invoke the callback function
            callback.onButtonClick()
        }
    }
}
```

I am using in `Activity` and `Fragment` like bellow:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity @Inject constructor() : AppCompatActivity(), ButtonCallback {
...

    override fun onButtonClick() {
        when (navController.currentDestination?.id) {
            R.id.navigation_lessons, R.id.navigation_lightner, R.id.navigation_quiz, R.id.navigation_profile, R.id.navigation_news -> {
                if (onBackPressedDispatcher.hasEnabledCallbacks()) {
                    onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
                } else {
                    navController.navigateUp()
                }
            }
            else -> {
                navController.navigateUp()
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

And:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class NewsFragment : Fragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var buttonCallback: ButtonHandler
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
...
        binding.imgBackNews.setOnClickListener {
            buttonCallback.setButtonClickListener(binding.imgBackNews)
        }
...
}
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    try {
        buttonCallback =
            context as ButtonHandler // callback instance
    } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
        throw ClassCastException("Calling Fragment must implement ButtonCallback")
    }
}
```

My problem is here (`onAttach`) how can I resolve this line (`buttonCallback = context as ButtonHandler`) for run these line `navController.currentDestination?.id` .....

My `MainActivity` is like bellow:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity @Inject constructor() : AppCompatActivity(), ButtonCallback {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
initNavigation()
}
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private fun initNavigation() {
        val navHost =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHost.navController
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navViewManin
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController)
        binding.navViewManin.setupWithNavController(navController)
        binding.navViewManin.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
            "Reselect blocked."
        }

    }

    override fun onButtonClick() {
        when (navController.currentDestination?.id) {
            R.id.navigation_lessons, R.id.navigation_lightner, R.id.navigation_quiz, R.id.navigation_profile, R.id.navigation_news -> {
                if (onBackPressedDispatcher.hasEnabledCallbacks()) {
                    onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
                } else {
                    navController.navigateUp()
                }
            }
            else -> {
                navController.navigateUp()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to run these lines navController.currentDestination?.id.

Comment: This didn't answer my question. Why are you casting Context to ButtonHandler (while also injecting ButtonHandler to your fragment)?

Comment: when fun onButtonClick() is empty it good work and I can see my log but when I fill it with navController... it say me lateinit property navController has not been initialized.

Comment: Can you show your initialization of navController variable?

Comment: Ok. I am editing my question.

Comment: Done my edit...